# Disable select option based on JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I use [Jiren filter library](https://github.com/jiren/filter.js) to filter JSON data.
So when I use some filter criteria I want to disable unused option in the `select`.

By example: in my result I don't have any cruise type "Silversea Expedition" I want this option disable in my filter.

Here it"s my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="well">
              <fieldset id="cruiseType_criteria">
                  <legend>Cruise Type</legend>
                  <select class="form-control" id="type_filter" role="listbox">
                      <option value="all">All</option>
                      <option value="Silversea Classic">Cruise</option>
                      <option value="Silversea Expedition">Expedition</option>
                  </select>
              </fieldset>
          </div>
```

**JSON Object:**

```
{
    "id": 23,
    "Destination": "Mediterranean",
    "DestinationID": "263960e8-9eaa-4ab0-a040-25bdf94479ee",
    "DepartureDate": "2016-02-09T04:45:01 -01:00",
    "Ship": "Explorer",
    "ShipID": "8b7571a9-1a73-40c3-916f-27b3981167d1",
    "CruiseType": "Silversea Classic",
    "Duration": 13,
    "AllInclusive": true,
    "WaitList": false,
    "FareFrom": 5434,
    "Currency": "$",
    "Cities": [
      "ad",
      "magna",
      "dolore",
      "quis",
      "magna",
      "sint",
      "consequat",
      "nostrud",
      "amet",
      "fugiat",
      "proident",
      "aliqua"
    ],
    "VoyageCode": "{{integer(100, 9999)}",
    "Features": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Diving"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Wellness"
      }
    ],
    "url": "silversea.com"
  },
```

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Considering your json data is in `jsonObj` and `CruiseType` is an array.

```
var cruiseType= jsonObj.cruseType;
$("#type_filter").each(function()
        {
            // checking if option is present in cruiseType array or not
            if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), cruiseType) == -1){
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
```

The above code will add `disbled=true` to the options which are not present in `CruiseType` from `jsonObj`.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help

Comment: It disables the control not an option. I put your  code in the _afterFilter_ var because it's used when I filter the data.

  
 `var afterFilter = function (result) {
        $('#total_cruises').text(result.length);

        var cruiseType= result.CruiseType;
        $("#type_filter").each(function()
        {
            // checking if option is present in cruiseType array or not
            if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), cruiseType) == -1){
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });


    }`
Thanks for the help

Comment: I'll look for option disable and let you know